# MySql query to get rows with only one connected row

Tags: mysql

I have a tables like that:

```
Products
ID | Name 
1  | Prod1
2  | Prod2
```

Product_history

```
ID | Product_id | quantity | order_id | date
1  | 1          | 10       | 1        | 2014-01-01 10:00:00
2  | 1          | 11       | 1        | 2014-01-01 11:00:00
3  | 1          | 20       | 2        | 2014-01-01 09:00:00
4  | 2          | 50       | 2        | 2014-01-01 09:00:00
```

I can't create query witch will return me all products with sum of quantities of each order by only with last date. In this example I want  to return:

```
product_id | quantity
1          | 31 (11 + 20)
2          | 50
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses `not exists`:

```
select ph.product_id, sum(ph.quantity)
from product_history ph
where not exists (select 1
                  from product_history ph2
                  where ph2.order_id = ph.order_id and
                        ph2.product_id = ph.product_id and
                        ph2.date > ph.date
                 )
group by ph.product_id;
```

If your tables are large, you want a composite index on `product_history(order_id, product_id, date)` for performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p1.product_id, sum(p1.quantity)
from product_history p1
join
(
  select product_id, max(date) as date
  from product_history
  group by product_id
) p2 on p1.product_id = p2.product_id and p1.date = p2.date
group by p1.product_id
```